# Pop up confirm message to appear on condition

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup, confirm, registerclientscriptblock

I am trying to set up a Confirm dialogue which works as follows:

When user clicks on Export button, calculations are done in the code-behind to work out how many rows to export. If row number exceeds a threshold (e.g. 1 million rows), the pop-up confirm message appears and asks if user would like to batch export and receive email when job is done.

I've been using this solution so far (obtained from [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Server-Side-Yes-No-Confirmation-Box-using-JavaScript.aspx)):

**Javascript:**

```
        function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to batch export data?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
```

**Code-Behind**

```
                string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
            if (confirmValue == "Yes")
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked YES!')", true);
            }
            else
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('You clicked NO!')", true);
            }
```

The the only problem I have is that regardless of whether the row number exceeds the threshold or not, the pop up confirm message appears, which is not what I want.

I want the pop up message to ONLY appear if the calculated row number exceed the threshold.

Any ideas?

Comment: where is the check for threshold v/s row number happening ?

Comment: its happening in the code-behind - onClick of the Export button. if row number > threshold, then pop up message occurs. thanks!

Comment: That should happen on the javascript side right? Or else the popup will always showup

Comment: Yea, that's exactly my problem - not wanting the pop up to always show up. Is there a way to do the calculation on the code-behind? Or does it always have to be done on the javascript side?

Comment: On javascript side, what variables store the value `row_number` and `threshold` ? Check this way: `if ((row_number > threshold) && confirm("Do you want to batch export data?")) `

Comment: Thanks!...maybe thats the way I would have to go!

I'm storing the row_number and threshold in Sessions e.g. Session["RowNumber"], Session["ColNumber"] etc. Whats the correct way to multiple 2 sessions above in Javascript and check it's within threshold of say 5000?

Comment: Actually scratch my above comment...I realised I am already storing the row number in a hiddenfield!

Comment: Oh.. your life is much simpler now.. Good luck